# Resolving an issue's checklist from pull request

Tags: github

Say I have an issue with checklist like so:

Issue #1:

```
This issue will fix the following things:

- [x] Checklist item 1
- [] Checklist item 2
- [] Checklist item 3
```

Now, I know that I can specify which issue to fix from the PR using terms like, fixes, resolves, etc. However, is there a way to specify in the PR what checklist item from the issue that PR fixes? So something like:

```
Fixes #1-#2, fixes #1-#3
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming issue